# List the tag of Subviews which are visible in a UIview

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have UIView, Initially i will have 4 subview, in runtime. my code will hide to 2 view, so i need the tag values of remaining two view which are visible, is it possible.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Nikhil.Ch

Answer (score 1):

First, iterate the subviews of the view. Check if the subview is a UIView class. From here, you can now check whether the subview is hidden or not.

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        if (!subview.isHidden) {
            NSLog(@"%i", subview.tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @iosDev82, the code snippet is straightforward. Added brief explanation though.